# Vertically merging cells and adding view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I am doing a program for a machine and I am using GridLayout. Columns represents the days of working of that machine and rows represent how many hour works that machine.Because of this I have to strech out cells such as three of them vertically and have to add a button from starting hour to ending hour.Of course that button has to fill that space but I can't.This is my problem.

Could you help me pls??

Thanks you in advance.

I would like to make it like this method.

```
public void addViewToGridLayout(View view, int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan) {
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
params.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column, columnSpan);
params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, rowSpan);

gridLayout.addView(view, params);
```

}

this code is writed by me but it does not do what I want

```
        GridLayout a = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.GridLayout1);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

        params.height=Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL;
        params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(3,2);
        params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(3);
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setLayoutParams(params);
        a.addView(b);

}
```

[image]

Comment: post a screen shot of what you are trying to achieve. also show some effort.. what have you tried so far and what is the problem...

Comment: I sent a screenshot of what I want to do. I do it from xml but I want to do it from sourcecode according to parameters.